# Correct use of AtomicReference.compareAndSet for a stack implementation

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

I was experimenting with java.util.concurrent and trying to work out how to use AtomicReference.compareAndSet correctly to manage concurrent access to a single unit of shared state.

In particular: is the following usage of compareAndSet correct and safe? Any pitfalls?

My test class is a simple stack based on a linked list of nodes.

```
public class LinkedStack<T> {

  AtomicReference<Node<T>> topOfStack=new AtomicReference<Node<T>>();

  public T push(T e) {
    while(true) {
      Node<T> oldTop=topOfStack.get();
      Node<T> newTop=new Node<T>(e,oldTop);
      if (topOfStack.compareAndSet(oldTop, newTop)) break;
    } 
    return e;
  }

  public T pop() {
    while(true) {
      Node<T> oldTop=topOfStack.get();
      if (oldTop==null) throw new EmptyStackException();
      Node<T> newTop=oldTop.next;
      if (topOfStack.compareAndSet(oldTop, newTop)) return oldTop.object;
    } 
  }

  private static final class Node<T> {
    final T object;
    final Node<T> next;

    private Node (T object, Node<T> next) {
      this.object=object;
      this.next=next;
    }
  } 
  ...................
}
```

Comment: The only thing that gives me pause is not how you're using `AtomicReference` but rather what you're returning from `push`.  I would sooner expect `push` to return nothing or the value that was being buried than the value you're pushing itself.

Comment: @Mark, yeah, that gave me pause too but I'm only trying to be consistent with Java's standard Stack - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html#push(E) - admit it's a slightly odd return definition

Comment: It's probably best to pretend that class doesn't exist for many reasons (it's not an interface when it should be, it uses inheritance from Vector instead of composition, etc.).  I would take your cues from the [Deque](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#push(E)) interface instead whose implementations are preferred over `Stack`.  It was introduced in Java 6 and `Stack`'s Javadoc was changed to suggest using `Deque` over `Stack`.

Comment: @Mark - yeah you're right, Queue or Deque is clearly a much better model :-) I think that the old Stack probably ought to be deprecated by now.....

Comment: The reason methods like push return the pushed object is because it allows for easy chaining of method calls: stack.push(new Integer(5)).intValue(); If only they would have made Collection#add to return the added object as well it would have been consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct in its current form.

Your structure is known as Treiber's Stack. It is a simple thread-safe lock-free structure that suffers from having a single point of contention (`topOfStack`) and therefore tends to scale badly (under contention it will thrash, and that doesn't play nicely with the MMU). It is a good option for if the contention is likely to be low but thread-safety is still required.

For further reading on scaling stack algorithms see "[A Scalable Lock-free Stack Algorithm (pdf)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.8774&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" by Danny Hendler, Nir Shavit and Lena Yerushalmi.

Comment: thanks! accepted your answer in particular because it was interesting to learn what this little construct is actually called :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's exactly how it should be used.

Perhaps the following syntax would be more elegant:

```
Node<T> oldTop = null;
Node<T> newTop = null;
do {
    oldTop=topOfStack.get();
    newTop=new Node<T>(e,oldTop);
} while (!topOfStack.compareAndSet(oldTop, newTop));
```

Comment: thanks for confirming! I wanted to do as you suggest but Java's scoping rules for oldTop and newTop didn't seem to allow it....

Comment: yeah I'm with @mikera in that I prefer proper scope with a weird exit more than the other way around.  But I agree with your assessment.

Answer (score 3):

It all looks good (nothing new from what axtavt said), the one thing I would think is worth noting is that the rate of a failed pop or push is now twice as high then with, say, a ConcurrentLinkedQueue.  When I say fail I just mean you will have to execute within the while loop again, assuming another thread pops or pushes before you.

Though this may be out of scope of what you are trying to achieve, some kind of backoff protocol will help performance in the event of high contention.